# loop not working in mysql Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
    read_loop:
LOOP
    FETCH device_cur INTO device;
    IF done1 THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    set x = start;
    repeat
        SET tripcount = 0;
        SET trip_previous = 0;
        SELECT MAX(distinct(trip)) into tripcount from model_erv40  where date(log_time) = date(x) and device_id = device;
        IF tripcount > 0 THEN
            set y = 1;
            repeat
                SET cd = 0;
                SELECT IFNULL(MAX(cumulative_distance), 0) into cd from model_erv40 where trip = y  and date(log_time) = date(x)  and device_id = device;
                if cd > 0 then
                    if trip_previous = 0 then
                        set cdold = 0;
                        set cdcorrect = cd;
                    else
                        SELECT IFNULL(MAX(cumulative_distance), 0) into cdold from model_erv40 where trip = trip_previous  and date(log_time) = date(x)  and device_id = device;
                        set cdcorrect = cd - cdold;
                    end if; 

                    SELECT users.id, users.verified INTO user_idv, verified FROM users INNER JOIN devices ON users.id = devices.user_id AND devices.id =  device;
                    SELECT IFNULL(attribute_value, '') INTO group_code from user_attributes ua where ua.user_id = user_idv and ua.attribute_id = 1;

                    INSERT INTO trip_info(trip, user_id, device_id, IsVerified, groupcode, date, cumulative_distance) VALUES (y, user_idv, device, verified,  IFNULL(group_code,''), x, ROUND(cdcorrect*0.0006214,2));
                    SET trip_previous = y;
                end if;

                set y = y + 1;
            until y > tripcount
            end repeat;
        END IF;
        set x = date_add(x, interval  1 day);
    until x > enddate
    end repeat;
END LOOP;
```

If i am removing the statement

> SELECT g.groupcode INTO group_code FROM users u INNER JOIN
>   user_attributes ua ON u.id = ua.user_id AND ua.attribute_id = 1 AND
>   u.id = user_id INNER JOIN   groupcode_master g ON ua.attribute_value =
>   g.groupcode;

then loop works fine and i am getting data for all the device but after adding that afore said statement i am getting data for only one device that means the loop is not continuing but i want to loop through all the device with the above statement. Please Help me ..Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `tripcount` and what is its value? What is the initial value of `y`?

Comment: SET tripcount = 0;
SET trip_previous = 0;
SELECT MAX(distinct(trip)) into tripcount from model_erv40  where date(log_time) = date(x) and device_id = device;

this is the count of trips made by the device per day.

Comment: And what are `log_time` and `x`? You checked their values are correct? My idea is that `tripcount` is 1 or 0 which explains why the loop executes only one time.

Comment: log_time = the time when data is sent from my device and  x = start date which i am getting by parameter

Comment: I have added the whole loop in that start and enddate are the start date and end date respectively and values got through parameters

Comment: I saw and out of ideas, sorry.. I edited the code however and made it much more readable, hopefully someone will figure this out soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two notes:

```
...
INNER JOIN user_attributes ua ON u.id = ua.user_id AND ua.attribute_id = 1 AND u.id = user_id
...
```

1. 'u.id = user_id' - if 'user_id' is a declared variable, it should be renamed because there is a field with the same name 'user_id'
2. ua.attribute_id = 1 - shouldn't it be in a WHERE clause?

Comment: I have changed the declared variable name to user_idv and the statement to "SELECT IFNULL(attribute_value, '') INTO group_code from user_attributes ua where ua.user_id = user_idv and ua.attribute_id = 1;".
One more thing user_attribute also contain the required value for group_code where attribute id is 1.

But still it is giving the same result i mean the loop is running only once.

Comment: I'd suggest you to debug this sp, you can do it with a debugger tool in dbForge Studio - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html